# Google Directory API always return 403 when using OAuth2.0 even after user consent

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-account, google-directory-api

I am working on a web app and struggling with Google Directory API.

The app is trying to get the list of the google groups user belongs to with the simple code as following:

```
from apiclient import discovery
from google.appengine.api import users
from oauth2client.appengine import OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets

def decorator():
    ....(some scopes including admin.directory.group)
    return decorator

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @decorator.oauth_required
    def get(self):
        me = users.get_current_user()

        http = oauth_decorator.http()
        service = discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)
        grouplist = service.groups().list(userKey=me).execute()
        ....
```

This results in **403 Not Authorized to access this resource** while Admin SDK is enabled. There are a lot of questions report similar problems but the major difference is I am trying to use OAuth2.0 instead of using service account, which means the user need explicitly consent and grant the authority I ask for.

So my guessing is for some reason, the request is not with the proper user authorization code, but I have no idea how I can prove my suspicion and how I can make it work. Any suggestions? Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Google and it turns out to be that I need to be domain administrator in order to use ANY Admin APIs listed.

Not quite feasible in my case, so I am trying to find ways around.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a scope defined for each API, the admin will need to grant a consent for it at the time of token generation.  If you are using OAuth2.0, once you generate a refresh token, you are good to go.